# "Always Use Auto" in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

C++ guru Herb Sutter proposes that we should almost always use "auto". He states this on his [website](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) and he recently repeated it at the [CppCon 2014 conference](http://youtu.be/xnqTKD8uD64).

I've tried to follow his advice and I'm not convinced. Is there someone here who agrees with Sutter and who can tell me why

```
auto gender = string{};
auto number = string{};
auto person = string{};
```

is better than

```
string gender, number, person;
```

which is what I ended up writing in my code, because I couldn't bear the auto style.

**Edit:**

```
auto gender = string{}, number = string{}, person = string{};
```

is also a possibility, but in my opinion that's even worse.

Comment: Do yourself and everyone else a favour and use std::string instead of string.

Comment: Declaring multiple variables on one line is usually frowned upon as well.

Comment: When you start working with templated types only, it will make sense to use auto (almost exclusively).

Comment: @Shaggi, I agree with you there. But "polluting" non-template code and making it less readable on the unlikely chance that it will some day become a template is not a good idea, IMO.

Comment: isn't this just personal habit? Well, I use auto in loops and cases where I can't tell the type

Comment: @oz1cz I usually only do it for arithmetic types (or emulating classes), where input is templated and temporary results are declared as auto. Stuff like containers, strings and the like i tend to typedef inside a namespace instead.

Comment: @oz1cz: How is using `auto` to be considered "less readable"?. I'd say it's the opposite. It means one of two things: a) I don't care what type it is, as long as the compiler knows it's the correct type. b) I've already provided the concrete type on the right side and don't want to repeat that redundantly on the left side.

Comment: It is a matter of taste, of course, but I find that two words (`string gender`) is easier both to read and write than three words plus some special characters (`auto gender = string{}`).

Comment: sticking to the title of your question, try not to use auto even if it is a cool toy. The reason is that if your code was to use in a legacy C++ system, this will break, won't it? I certinaly had this problem. You can write protective code to determine if C++11 is available (and thereofore, use auto).

Comment: @hagubear I hope this is sarcasm...

Comment: @luk32          you are saying that if he uses auto all the time and try to retarget his application for C++89 or something before C++11 compiler, it will be fine?

Comment: @hagubear I am saying that this is creepily twisted logic. Why would anyone retarget. With this logic every one should revert to c. Maybe the c++ committee should disband, because what it the point of their work, if we should stick to `c++89` "just in case". I won't even comment on the idea of doubling the code with preprocessing whether or not compiler is c++11 compilant.

Comment: @luk32         If you had any experience of supporting legacy C/C++ applications done without C++11-specific features, you would think otherwise. I have had to support systems that were designed using C/C++ compilers much older than C++11. The migration cost was something that no one wanted to get into. You cannot expect each and everyone to be able to switch just like that! I am simply saying that take measures and be prepared to support everything.

Comment: @oz1cz: Yeah, `auto` is overused. No, it's not beneficial to use `auto` everywhere, contrary to what Herb Sutter says.

Comment: @hagubear "*You cannot expect each and everyone to be able to switch just like that!*" - precisely, that is why you first make a (business) decision for a project what standards you will/need to support, with all the pros and cons. "*I am simply saying that take measures and be prepared to support everything.*" - and this is faulty logic. It is impossible, literally, to be prepared for everything. Doing things "just in case" is obstructing your development process for no reason. Technical constraints and requirements should be clear before the 1st line of code.

Answer (score 2):

The auto keyword should mainly be used in cases where you initialize the variable with a value, as this makes the code more maintainable in cases where you change the value you initialize the variable with:

```
uint16_t id_ = 65535;

uint16_t id()
{
    return id_;
}

auto myid = id();
```

No need to change the type of `myid` if `id()` return type changes.

And with C++14 it gets even better:

```
uint16_t id_ = 65535;

decltype(auto) id()
{
    return id_;
}

auto myid = id();
```

Changing the type of `id_` automatically adjusts the return type of `id()` and the type of `myid`.

In cases where the initial value of the variable is not initialized with a value and as such is not dependent on other code for initialization, it makes sense to explicitly define the variable type, as the auto keyword would not add more maintainability to the code and the syntax `auto gender = string{};` is less readable than `string gender;`.

Comment: You're right in this case. But the question concerns a case where there is a straightforward construction of an object with is default constructor. I have no problems with auto in the situation you mention here, but I do feel that `type variable` is simpler and more readable than `auto variable = type{}`.

Comment: Ah, right, I assumed it was a more general question.

Your case is an example of why he says "almost always". If you create your objects in a local function scope, it also makes sense that you know what the type is and as such should declare a variable of that type. `auto` should be used for variables where you get the value from somewhere else and can initialize it from that value (as this makes the code more maintainable, like I shoved in my answer).

Comment: Updated the answer to better answer the actual question.